# Find missing item in a list grouped

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections

I have a list of objects `dailySchedule` with the properties Order, District, and other properties.

```
public class dailySchedule
{
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public string Title { get;  }
        public string District { get;  }
        ....
}
```

the list is loaded with these values

[image]

Each district must have 6 orders,

`var ordersValue = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};`

I want to find for each district, which order is missing.

The result must be 
District 0  order {2,3,5,6}
District 12 order {5,6}

How can do that with linq c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code which will give you result with each district and its missing orders

```
        var allOrders = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        var result = orders.GroupBy(gp => gp.District).Select(sl =>
            new { District = sl.Key, Order = allOrders.Where(wh => sl.All(all => all.Order != wh)) });
```

Comment: Hi Harisyam, Thank you also for your solution :) Best Regards.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case for `Except()`:

you can achieve your desired result by *"substracting two lists"* like so:

```
var required = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

var groupedByDistrict = orders.GroupBy(x => x.District);
foreach (var group in groupedByDistrict)
{
    var missing = required.Except(group.Select(x => x.Order).Distinct());

    // Do something with that informaton here
}
```

**This is mere non working pseudocode to get you on the right track**
 actually it may work, but i haven't tested it.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thank you very much, It work, like i wanted.